# How to fix this existing shadow shader/material with alpha textures?

Tags: shaders, hlsl, ogre, fragment-shader, mogre

I hope I could get some help here in finally resolving this problem of mine re: shadow casting with alpha textures.

Here's a screenshot on what I am hoping for as a result:

[image]

A friend of mine just sent this shader program to help out but I still can't get it to work properly. The alpha textures such as leaves still leave a rectangular shadow. I'm using a custom built Ogre based engine but overall the material and compositor system is still the same.

Attachment:
[Alpha_Shader.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pwt18i56em0nhr/Alpha_Shader.zip)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must sample your alpha texture in the depth buffer creation fragment shader, which is ShadowCasterFP in your code. When you sampled the texture, you should discard pixels below a certain alpha level, or do a clip:

```
if( color.a<0.1 ) 
 discard;

clip( color.a<0.1?-1:1 );
//where color is your sampled texture at the current fragment
```

These two will do the same, which is not outputting any color to your rendertarget/depthmap.

**EDIT:**
You'd have to insert the above code (either the discard or the clip) to your MVSMShadows.hlsl to the beginning of the ShadowCasterFP function. But you also have to sample a texture resource and a sampler there which you must declare and upload to the GPU beforehand. You can declare a texture and a sampler like this:

```
Texture2D<float4> myTexture : register(t0); //texture bound to the first texture slot
SamplerState mySampler : register(s0); //sampler unit bound to the first sampler slot
```

Then you must sample that texture while creating the shadow map:

```
float4 color = myTexture.Sample(mySampler,In.texCoords);
```

So you have your fragment color which contains an alpha. You check that alpha and discard if it is too low with clip or discard.

Comment: Hey, thank you for this info. Honestly, I don't have any background in shader programming so could you kindly provide a revised code based on the files that I sent? I'm not sure if they are working or where to place the corresponding additions that you mentioned. Perhaps via Pastebin? Thanks again.

Comment: Added some info in the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot János! I think I'm now getting somewhere but I'm not sure where to place the texture and sampler line you mentioned above, is it still under ShadowCasterFP function? And the float4 color.. goes into ShadowReceiverFP right? I don't know where to exactly place the last 2 codes but so far I got this on **MVSMShadows.hlsl** http://pastebin.com/0shkvLqu and my update **Tree.material** is this http://pastebin.com/jTahK13i

Comment: The texture and sampler declarations go outside of the function, like you are declaring uniforms, the color goes into the function before the clip.

Comment: Ok thanks. I now got this snippet on my MVSMShadows.hlsl http://pastebin.com/xWanPsCX I still can't get the alpha texture shadows to work.. :(

Comment: Did you upload a texture into the slot which you specified in the shader? I don't know how to do that in ogre though, you have to look it up yourself.

Comment: I guess not yet. Is this going to be on the material file of the model? and can you provide an example or reference to it on non Ogre? Right now I got this on my material file if this is what you mean.. http://pastebin.com/FQ4yNSxj

Comment: You can see there is a xyz.PNG in your material file. It means that a material loader would load that png file for you from the disk to the gpu memory. Once you want to draw a model with that material, you should set its texture as the active texture on GPU slot 0 somehow (or to a slot which is specified in your shader with :register(t0)).

Comment: Ok I still don't know how to do this. Another question: Why is the MVSMShadows.hlsl only the modified file here and not the cg file? Is there any difference? My friend who abandoned this code got this working with the MVSMShadows.cg file as reference to the screenshot above but somehow got messed up the code that he sent me. He told me he did not made any changes to the hlsl file. I'm really puzzled right now. Sorry for the many questions and thanks for helping so far János..

Comment: I only know the hlsl thats's why, sorry I couldn't help much.

Comment: No worries as you've been a great help and somehow got me started to better understand this problem. Thank you.